How to prepare complex JSON payload with dynamic attributes in Power Automate Flow
I've one complex problem in Power Automate. Please HELP!!
I'm using two tables 'new_demotable001' and 'new_metadatatable'. One to trigger the flow and another as Mapping Sheet, respectively.
By using both I want to create a JSON payload that I'll use to call external API. Please help me create the payload.
<Details/Prerquisite>

When a new row added in new_demotable001, flow triggers.
The data/attributes we will receive from table are - Note: I've removed unnecessary attributes.

{
  "statecode": 0,
  "_statecode_label": "Active",
  "statuscode": 1,
  "_statuscode_label": "Active",
  "new_empstatus": 100000001,
  "new_empname": "EmpName909",
  "new_empcontact": "9090990909090909",
  "new_empexperience": "100000000,100000001,100000002"
}


Then fetch details from 'new_metadatatable' table using "List Rows".
The data/attributes we will receive from table are - Note: I've removed unnecessary attributes.

{
  "@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.totalrecordcount": -1,
  "@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.totalrecordcountlimitexceeded": false,
  "@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.globalmetadataversion": "11353407",
  "value": [
    {
      "new_sirionattributetype": "TEXT",
      "new_sirionattributename": "title",
      "new_dynamicsattributename": "new_empname"
    },
    {
      "new_sirionattributetype": "NUMERIC",
      "new_sirionattributename": "test1",
      "new_dynamicsattributename": "new_empcontact"
    },
    {
      "new_sirionattributetype": "SINGLE_REF",
      "new_sirionattributename": "orgId",
      "new_dynamicsattributename": "new_empstatus"
    },
    {
      "new_sirionattributetype": "MULTI_REF",
      "new_sirionattributename": "sirionExp",
      "new_dynamicsattributename": "new_empexperience"
    }
  ]
}


Now, I want to create a JSON payload using above attributes. To create payload we will use only those attributes which are present in 'new_metadatatable' and also coming from 'new_demotable001'. -> The Condition I used - contains(triggerOutputs()?['body'], items('Apply_to_each')?['new_dynamicsattributename'])

'new_sirionattributetype' attribute value defines the structure of Expected Output Payload.
If 'new_sirionattributetype' is TEXT/NUMERIC Output Payload will be normal JSON, if it is SINGLE_REF then Output Payload will have object {}, if it is MULTI_REF then Output Payload will have array object [].

For above set of data, the expected output payload should be-


{
    "data": {
        "orgId": {
            "id": 100000001
        },
        "test1": "9090990909090909",
        "title": "EmpName909",
        "sirionExp": [
            {
                "id": 100000000
            },
            {
                "id": 100000001
            },
            {
                "id": 100000002
            }
        ]
    }
}

Please help me with this complex problem.
Also suggest, if this can be acheived by any other method like using script or something.

Note: The payload given above is just for reference. In future the number of attributes will be changed as per the user.

Here's a simple architecture that works for any payloads irrespective of the values and fields or number of values coming in.
You can merge them into a single loop and apply conditions for branching. However, i have made it separately for better understanding of what's going on.
What i did:

filter out the metadata that have a corresponding value in 'data' table
create three groups i.e text & numbers, objects and arrays
merge text and numbers as it is
convert objects into required schema using a compose.
convert arrays to an array of required schema by splitting the items by a ','
to merge the objects, We use Add Property function. Make sure your loop's concurrency is 1 otherwise it will be overwritten.

Here's the final output:

Here's the detailed steps for each group.



dont get confused with the "compose" within each loop. it is like a temporary storage for the JSON variable since power automate does not support self references and incrementing the variables.

Thanks @LavizaFalakNaz. This is really helpful. :)
